# Provide commit access to people for restricted files in svn hooks

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I have a pre-commit hook that fails commit if anyone is trying to commit restricted files. However, i want to provide access to certain people who can commit by bypassing pre-commit hook. Let me know how can i do it. I'm not much expert in scripting.

Pre-Commit hook:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

LOGMSG=$($SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS")

# check if any comment has supplied by the commiter
if [ -z "$LOGMSG" ]; then
echo "Your commit was blocked because it have no comments."
exit 1
fi 1>&2

#check minimum size of text
if [ ${#LOGMSG} -lt 15 ]; then
echo "Your Commit was blocked because the comments does not meet minimum length requirements (15 letters)."
exit 1
fi 1>&2

# get TaskID by regex
TaskID=$(expr "$LOGMSG" : '\([#][0-9]\{1,9\}[:][" "]\)[A-Za-z0-9]*')

# Check if task id was found. 
if [ -z "$TaskID" ]; then

echo   
echo "No Task id found in log message \"$LOGMSG\"" 
echo   
echo "The TaskID must be the first item on the first line of the log message."  
echo   
echo "Proper TaskID format--> #123- 'Your commit message'  " 
exit 1
fi 1>&2

#Check that QA should not be present in log message.

if grep -q ' QA\>' <<< "$LOGMSG"; then
    echo
    echo "Your log message \"$LOGMSG\" must not contain QA in upper case."
    echo
    exit 1
fi 1>&2

#Check that restricted files should not get commited.

if [ -x ${REPOS}/hooks/restrict_files.sh ]; then
echo
${REPOS}/hooks/restrict_files.sh "${REPOS}" "${TXN}" 
fi 1>&2
```

restrict_files.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

#Check that restricted files should not get commited.

RESFILES=$($SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS")

if grep -E '/*/httpdocs/libs/class.logs.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/app/models/login.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/app/controller/login.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/check_session.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/index.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/config/db.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/config/path.php'\|'/*/httpdocs/Salesp/config/constant.php'\|'/*/generic/common/CarrierConstants.php'\|'/*/generic/Carrier/GetVendorCommonFunction.php' <<< "$RESFILES" >/tmp/rest.txt; then

echo
echo "You are trying to commit restricted files:"
rest=$(</tmp/rest.txt)
echo "$rest"
echo
exit 1
fi 1>&2
```

Comment: It is a recommended practice to include the code in the question. The question is considered to be off-topic if it does not has any code.

Comment: @bahrep can you please assist, as i have added scripts as well.